# Graduate of Graphic Design, want to pursue Applied Mathematics for physical modeling. Can I get Recognition, either Certificate or Degree?

Tags: mathematics, education

I have a bachelor's degree in graphic design (US resident). I recently got interested in real-time physical modeling of instruments; after realizing that I needed math to do what I want, I started self learning. I completed Stitz and Zeager's college Precalculus book, and now I'm going through UBC's CLP Calc 1 book. I ultimately intend to be able to apply: solving partial differential equations with transformations and space/time discretization, vector calculus, complex analysis, state-space models, Volterra series, etc. So far, I'm having fun and I intend to keep going, as I'm extremely motivated about this subject (physical modeling). Looking at the subjects/topics I want to learn, they essentially make up an applied math program (especially when looking at MIT's course list for Physical Applied Math).

I was thinking, since I want to learn what is essentially applied math, why not get a certificate, degree, or some kind of recognition that could help in my professional development in the future? Problem is, most graduate programs require students to already have done several math courses I've yet to learn. Is there a way for a US non-math grad like me to "officially" complete the prerequisites to get into an applied math program?

Comment: Have you looked into the possibility of taking courses at a nearby college or university? Even in the case of a community college, you should be able to take differential and integral calculus (single variable calculus), and for some community colleges even multivariable calculus and differential equations. I think once you get to this point (what you can do at a local community college), you'll be in a much better position to decide whether (and how) to continue. You'll also meet teachers and other students who you can talk to about your goals.

Comment: Yes, that's a good idea. However, I have a few months that I'm spending full time to learn math, and so being confined to spend an entire subject on one semester like Calc 1 before a second semester of Calc 2 isn't really ideal. I'm thinking I can self study at my faster pace and take CLEP tests to earn college credit, for at least the classes that must be taken in sequence. Then I can attend a college for classes I can take concurrently?

Comment: If you're pretty sure you will have the opportunity to CLEP the courses, and you're confident of your ability to self-study, then that would probably be better (no travel; no dealing with on-line classes) and probably much quicker and definitely less expensive (although community college costs tend to be quite low). Make sure you use an appropriate text (what's used where you're at), and don't rely on over-the-top recommendations I sometimes see for someone (in the U.S. at least) beginning to learn calculus (i.e. avoid the books [discussed here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/79865/13130)).